# Changing autogrow settings with database mirroring

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, mirroring

Recently I changed the Autogrow settings for some of the databases on our SQL Server 2008 R2 server. These are involved in a database mirroring configuration, with the principal on *SERVER1* and the mirror on *SERVER2*.

This week I failed over three databases- now *SERVER1* is the mirror and *SERVER2* is the principal for these databases. It appears that the autogrow settings did not move over to *SERVER2* properly, as the databases now show that they grow by a percentage (two are set to  32768%, the other to 131072%).

This is different than the settings that used to be there (I believe it was the default- 10%), and also different that the 256MB I set on *SERVER1*.

To make things more confusing, this is only happening on the primary file- the secondary files and log file has retained the settings I set on *SERVER1*.

My suspicion is that this is a bug- I did patch SQL after changing the autogrow settings. My question is- has anyone seen this scenario before? Is there a method to make sure all of the settings are correct on both servers without failing all the databases over?

**UPDATE:** Using a 4th database that I'll call *DB1*, I set the autogrow on *SERVER1* to 512MB (after failing the database over, witnessing the same issue, and failing it back). When I failed it over to *SERVER2* after that, it shows growth of 65536%. The takeaway is that the `is_autogrow_percent` value in `sys.master_files` is not moving to *SERVER2*, but the `growth` value is.

**UPDATE2:** With *DB1* on *SERVER1*, I changed the autogrow to 10% and failed it to *SERVER2*. The 10% value remained. I then repeated this, setting autogrow back to 256MB this time. Again, the `growth` value changed but the `is_autogrow_percent` did not.

Comment: Potentially related: http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/127177/autogrowth-in-mb-comes-back-as-after-reboot and http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/126336/attaching-a-database-increases-autogrowth-to-12800

Comment: Interesting- those two issues are the same failure mode, just triggered by different events (attaching a database, rebooting a server, failing over a mirrored database).

Comment: Yeah, same symptom, different cause, no idea about a fix - other than manually setting the autogrow rate after any such event. I know some people even have background jobs that check the settings multiple times daily...

Comment: I guess that is the route I'll be going down. I'm just glad I discovered this before we actually grew a file by 30,000% :)

Comment: I have seen a similar bogus autogrow issue. The funny thing is that you may get an error before you run out of disk space, possibly drawing attention to the issue. In your case (30,000%) for example: If the file was 1 GB and the time to autogrow came, first it would grow to 300 GB, and then next time, it would need 90 TB of space. Not that I am saying this is a good thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm addressing the issue using Policy Based Management. I created a policy on the `Data File` facet that states all files must have `@GrowthType = KB`.

I also filed a connect item: 
https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/796354/autogrow-is-percent-flag-set-on-principal-does-not-persist-to-mirror

UPDATE: This is fixed in SQL Server 2008 R2 SP2 CU8 and SP1 CU13.